# Delphi 7 edit component creation

Tags: delphi, user-interface

I have a problem according to run-time creation of edit components in Delphi 7.
So when I create TEdit components after the program ran for "some" time it perfectly works.
However, when I create TEdit elements at the Forms OnCreate event, they have a wrong height.
Furthermore the (almost) simultaneously created Shapes have the right height.

[image: The red marked Edits are created in the Forms OnCreate procedure, while the others are created on another event.]

Edit:

```
procedure TTPLVisorForm.CreateZeichen(ZShape : TShape; ZEdit : TEdit; VLeft : integer);
begin
  with ZShape do
  begin
    Width := 50;
    Height := 50;
    Left := VLeft;
    Top := 25;
    Shape := stRectangle;
    Parent := self.Band;
    SendToBack();
  end;

  with ZEdit do
  begin
    Text := '#';
    Left := VLeft+1;
    Top := 26;
    Parent := self.Band;
    Font.Height := 48;
    Width := 48;
    Height := 48;
    SendToBack;
  end;
end;
```

Getting called by:

```
procedure TZeichen.Anzeigen(Form : TObject; Left : integer);
begin
  self.Form := Form;

  self.ZShape := TShape.Create(TTPLVisorForm(self.Form).Band);
  self.ZEdit := TEdit.Create(TTPLVisorForm(self.Form).Band);

  TTPLVisorForm(Form).CreateZeichen(self.ZShape, self.ZEdit, Left);
end;
```

Getting called by:

```
procedure TMagnetband.ErweitereRechts;
var
  Zeichen : TZeichenKette;
begin
  Zeichen := TZeichenKette.Create;
  self.LetztesZeichen.Naechstes := TZeichenKette(Zeichen);
  Zeichen.Vorheriges := self.LetztesZeichen;

  Zeichen.Zeichen.Anzeigen(self.Form,
                                      self.LetztesZeichen.Zeichen.ZShape.Left +
                                      self.LetztesZeichen.Zeichen.ZShape.Width +
                                      self.Padding);
  self.LetztesZeichen := Zeichen;
  self.Laenge := self.Laenge+1;
end;
```

Getting again called by:

```
procedure TTuringmaschine.ZeichenAnfuegen;
begin
  self.Magnetband.ErweitereRechts;
end;
```

Getting called by:

```
procedure TTuringmaschine.PanelResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  while self.Magnetband.GetRechtsMax < self.Panel.Width do
    self.ZeichenAnfuegen;
end;
```

Finally gets called by:

```
Constructor TTuringmaschine.Create(Form : TObject);
var
  Breite : integer;
begin
  self.Zustand := 0;
  self.Form := TTPLVisorForm(Form);
  self.Panel := TTPLVisorForm(self.Form).Band;
  self.Magnetband := TMagnetband.Create(self.Form);
  TTPLVisorForm(Form).Band.OnResize := self.PanelResize;

  self.PanelResize(Nil);
  //self.CreateMagnetkopf;
end;
```

And the Constructor is either called at the OnCreate event or on another event.

Comment: Don't make us guess what your code is. Provide a cutdown program that gives repro.

Comment: Complete program please, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, please supply a complete program that we can immediately run. Why can't you do that?

Comment: Turn the `AutoSize` of your `ZEdit` in the `CreateZeichen` method off. And, of course decrease the height of the font since there's a margin around the text, so you can't have a control 48 pixels height if you use 48 px font height. Font height 40 fit into that background shape.

Comment: Turning the AutoSize off works! Post as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a margin around the text in `TEdit` control, so if you set the `Font.Height` to 48, the height of the control won't be exactly 48 if the control has the `AutoSize` property set to True. I would personally decrease height of the font, and for being sure turn the `AutoSize` off. Your `CreateZeichen` method would then look like this:

```
procedure TTPLVisorForm.CreateZeichen(ZShape: TShape; ZEdit: TEdit;
  VLeft: Integer);
begin
  with ZShape do
  begin
    Width := 50;
    Height := 50;
    Left := VLeft;
    Top := 25;
    Shape := stRectangle;
    Parent := Self.Band;
    SendToBack;
  end;

  with ZEdit do
  begin
    AutoSize := False;
    Text := '#';
    Left := VLeft + 1;
    Top := 26;
    Parent := Self.Band;
    Font.Height := 40;
    Width := 48;
    Height := 48;
    SendToBack;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I still don't get why the same code worked when called later, but at least it makes it working. Thank you!

Comment: "I still don't get why the same code worked when called later." Only you have any hope of understanding that because only you have the code. Please don't hide the code from us. Take the time needed to give us all the information we need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't want to hide the code, but it's currently in 8 units. I'll open a git soon though.